# PCB design review (ATmega32U4 keyboard PCB)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, keyboard, review, atmega32u4

I've been working on an ATmega32U4-based PCB for a custom keyboard for a while now. I made a few prototypes with similar designs, but they all seemed to have issues with the microcontrollers dying after a short while of use.

The symptoms are that the board works perfectly fine for a few minutes after first connected but then disconnects according to Windows. Unplugging and replugging the board results in another few Windows connect and disconnect sounds but with no response from the board. None of the keys I am activating are making it to the computer and hitting reset to put the controller into bootloader also results in no response.

I've included a few screenshots of the schematic and board layout below as well as a [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PYx7vxeJdVYWah3gNHkZT9lzKoSnWDg4?usp=sharing) with the BOM and the Kicad design files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been frustrating me for months now.

**Note:** I have changed one thing since my last prototype and the design files that I attached here. I had a trace crossing the traces going to the crystal on the top side of the board which I was advised could cause some interference. I changed that trace (labeled COL5) to now avoid crossing anything crystal related even if on the opposite side of the board.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What strategy are using for reading keys? Are you pulling rows low and then reading off the columns?

Comment: Is there a GND plane hidden or is this all the copper verbatim?

Comment: How's the software? Or fuse bits? Are you actually using the external crystal and does it work?

Comment: @TimWilliams That is all the copper there is. It is kind of the bare minimum right now.

Comment: @Justme I am using QMK firmware on the software side. As for the fuse, it is integrated in the daughterboard I'm using to connect to USB. The crystal should be used as dictated by QMK. I thought the 32u4 didn't have an integrated crystal so I have to use the external one.

Comment: @jramsay42 The matrix is read from column to row. I'm not sure if that answers your question but that's all I can really say from my knowledge.

Comment: @AndrewChao I did not mean fuses, I meant how are AVR programmable configuration bits called fuse bits set. If you are using ready-made firmware, are you sure you made the hardware to match the firnware? Please add all information what additional hardware and software you are using to figure out what's wrong. Right now you might just be fitting random puzzle pieces together and they are not necessarily compatible. Or you have one malfunctioning piece somewhere.

Comment: @Justme Honestly, I'm not well versed on the very specifics behind all of this but I've made a few boards with the exact same components before that weren't using a daughterboard that worked fine. QMK assumes a 16MHz crystal by default to my understanding which is what I am using. I'm pretty much using the exact components suggested by one of the most experience keyboard PCB designers, ai03. Details about the firmware can be found at https://qmk.fm/ if that helps whatsoever. I'm sorry I'm pretty lost when it comes to software and really technical stuff like this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please edit the hardware and software you are using into your question, with links, so that it is 100% sure what hardware and software items you are using together. Have you also considered if you have a manufacturing error which is not visible in schematics or PCB layout, but in your physical PCB?

Answer (score 1):

I always put TVS diodes on VBUS, D+ and D-, for example DRTR5V0U4S-7. As well as bypass capacitors and a series ferrite chip in series with VBUS, and I have never experienced problems with Atmega32U4.

Comment: This might be true, but likely TVS diodes being absent from data bus does not cause this.

Comment: @Justme TVS absent from +5V could cause damage from hot-plugging though, and the D+/- clamping is added value.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am using a daughterboard to connect the board to USB. The daughterboard has a TPD4E05U06DQAR for ESD protection, fuse, TVS diode for VBUS, and a ferrite bead inductor. It is the Unified Daughterboard designed by ai03 and a few other experienced keyboard designers for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Given the symptoms you have described, and your schematic, the first thing I can think of is that you may be exceeding the maximum current on the I/O ports.

There is a maximum for individual pins, and the datasheet indicates the sum of currents for certain combinations of pins should be < 100 mA.

Comment: It is scanning a matrix. How would that exceed rated pin current by itself? Except if the buttons are pushed and it shorts incorrectly configured IO pins.

Comment: Is there a “correct” way to configure to IO pins in a matrix like this? Are there certain pins that can’t be shorted together? Sorry I’m not that well versed on the actual specifics behind the ATMega32u4

Comment: @AndrewChao If COL are driven then how are you pulling down the ROW signals? ATMega32u4 has no pull-downs and I see none on the schematic. I hope they aren't hard driven low?